# Fully Convolutional network (FCN) desired output

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement a simple FCN in MATLAB from scratch. I have implemented 1 input (single channel image) neuron, 3 hidden layers with 3 neurons and one output neuron at end of the network as the following image:

[image: Network architecture]

and I want this network to have the input image and train so it could output the image as following (Left: Input, Right: Output(desired)):

[image: Left: Input, Right: Output(desired)]

Is my desired image correct as output of FCN? Is there any extra, necessary layer at end of network so it could produce the desired output? There are some explanations that FCN produces heatmaps, and heatmaps are different from desired images, if this is correct, how to compare the output at each iteration with desired (error for backpropagation)?

Answer (score 1):

It can produce anything if you don`t specify the loss and the ground truth(assume it is supervised).

That`s saying, if for each input image, you have a ground truth for output image, and for example the loss is MSE(input,output), then the training will fit a model that minimize the MSE between the input dataset and the output dataset. And hopefully, the generalization ability of the model is strong enough to produce your desired output for some arbitary input.

So you need to define the loss (and ground truth for supervised learning).

Comment: It is a supervised network, you can see a sample of both input and desired output (ground truth) of my data-set in my question. I have just manually created my desired images by reversing the color and removing the little dot in the top right corner of my input image. currently I am feeding the input (left image) and compare the output of network with the desired (right image). and for comparison and error I simply do : desired - networkOutPut. My actual question is that can I directly compare desired (shown in my post) with output of the network or it need some other steps?

Comment: I am confused of networkOutPut: is that from the toolbox (I don`t have the latest version of matlab)? But in terms of "error", what you need is to calculate the loss you defined. The easiest one is to calculate the mean square error between your desired output and the one calculated by the network (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error).

Comment: networkOutPut is output of my last neuron in network, and I'm not using toolbox, I just defined neuron and convolution myself. MSE is used to analyse squared mean error just for statistics, It cant be used for back-propagation. Still my question is about my ground truth (my desired images), is that considered as direct output of the network or the output of network needs to be compared with some sort of heatmap instead?!

Comment: You did not get what I said. If the ground truth (you put into the last layer for the comparison) is exactly what you want, then the output of model is an approach to your output. If your ground truth is a heat map, then it will be an approach to your heatmap.  By "approach" that is because usually there is still loss (difference to the ground truth) and hence, not perfect.   FCN is merely a regression model so the output fully depends on your ground truth.

Comment: I see, you mean its okey just to use any type of desires (ground truth), so my desired sample is correct.

Comment: If I correctly understand what you said, then yes. Simply consider FCN as a regression model.

Comment: if you take a look at my Input and ground truth, my network should remove the little dot on right corner, and FCN just consist of convolution filters, I don't see how a set of filters can remove an object and not remove the other one with same color (gray level), that is the reason I suspected there may be other layers that perform final pixel-vise classification!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem  This might help. You may consider such dot-removal is a function and the neural network will approximate this function.  Deeper network introduces more non-linearity and also the ability of generalization, so with sufficient input, it is possible to approximate it. However, the result varies depends on the detail of your hidden layers and hyperparameters and there are no good ways to tell so far.

Comment: I recommend you try it first with different hidden layer architectures. PS, it is not only "a set of filters", but also the non-linear activation functions as well. The non-linearity matters. You may also start from simpler tasks: i.e. inverse the pixel (white <--> black, assume this is also part of your goal) of the input manually first, and then let the FCN remove the dot).

Comment: yes I have the activation functions too, I use Relu. with this architecture (3 hidden layers) the color conversion (white <--> black) works fine, but it doesn't matter how many iteration it does, the dot will not get removed. Can I have your email to connect with you with sample code?